# Section doesn't change after modifying script

Tags: wordpress

This is a long shot, but I came to a wall and I don't have any idea what to do with it.

There is a site that has section with Google Maps map with custom pins. Location of the pins and configuration of the map are defined in wp-content/themes/mytheme/js/map.js file. I have to add some pins. According to the person who created the site a couple of years ago, new pins may be added by modifying map.js file.

The problem is - nothing changes when I modify this file. Even better - I can remove this file (and all other scripts in "js" folder) and nothing changes. This is the only instance of a script that I found.

There isn't any caching plugin enabled.
There isn't caching on server.
This is not browser cache.

Basically it seems like instead of loading this script, the site is taking it from different location, but I don't have a clue where it could be. Is there anything I can do to find source location of a script?

EDIT: I deleted all css and js folders entirely from FTP and it still shows in browsers. I entered Chrome web tools and used network tab to see initiator for the script and it shows as

xxxxxxxxxxx.xx/wp-content/themes/xxxxxxxxxx/js/map.js?ver=5.2.10

But this file DOES NOT EXIST. I deleted it via FTP. Same thing happens with CSS files. It isn't browser caching because it happens on different browsers, different computers...

Comment: Same problem here...  Anyone?

Comment: Nvm, it was stupid mistake.